# Crashes not showing in Crashlytics after migrating from Fabric

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Until now, I've had a link between Fabric and Firebase Crashlytics, so prior to today, I had all of my app's crashes show up in Firebase Crashlytics.

Today, I decided to completely migrate from Fabric to Firebase by following Google's migration guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

I've followed it exactly, and have gone through it half a dozen times to make sure everything is correct. Yet, when I force a crash and check my Firebase Crashlytics, none of my dozen+ crashes are showing up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNcv8.png

It's showing I have 77.78% crash-free users, but none of the crashes are actually showing up.

What am I missing? Why aren't the crashes showing up?

---

**Edit:**

I discovered that it shows crashes when using the `debug` build type, but it's not working for `release`. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

It looks like an issue with Proguard/R8. Tried a dozen different things but nothing seems to be helping. Possibly a dependency is affecting this?

Comment: Are you certain you're re-running the app (after your crash) w/o the debugger attached?

Comment: Remember there is some latency between the time when the SDK in your app will phone home to Firebase with the batch of crash reports it has logged.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, no debugger attached, I've cleaned and rebuilt the app a number of times, and I've invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio. Nothing works.

Comment: How long are you waiting? I'd give yourself 5-10min max.

Comment: @Aaron It's been almost 12 hours since I triggered the first crash. Additionally, prior to the migration, crashes were showing up almost instantly.

Comment: One thing I've done in the past is hook up a proxy between my app and the internet so I can see if in-fact the SDK is phoning home to Firebase with the crash log.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the Android set up as I am with iOS. On iOS if you have this problem, another issue might be the app's dSYMs are not getting to Firebase.

Comment: @Aaron I believe dSYM is similar to Proguard on Android. If so, I've also gone through these steps with no luck: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android

Comment: I wish I had a good answer for ya. I've exhausted all my tips/tricks for interfacing w/ Firebase ;-)

Comment: If it's showing up for debug and not release, I would check to see if there are any deltas between the two. Also, what does your environment look like between the two? Are they defined as buildtypes using one codebase, or are they separate apps?

Also, I would try onboarding your app going through these steps https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android, not the upgrade SDK doc. Make sure that you also remove ALL Fabric dependencies in your integration, and just to be sure, redownload your google-services file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that one of my other dependencies, https://github.com/ACRA/acra, was the culprit. Removing that dependency fixed my issues.